# How to use polymer tooltip tipattribute

Tags: polymer

How do I use the polymer tooltip tipAttribute?

I tried:

```
  <core-tooltip label="test" tipAttribute="color:red">
```

but it has no effect.
Thanks
Steve

Comment: It's actually `paper-tooltip`. See https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tooltip

Comment: it looks like the tipAttribute is to pass a attribute name and value and not a style or something

Comment: Attribute wrote wrong: <core-tooltip label="test" tip-attribute="color:red">